# OpenStack architecture and setup

Tags: openstack

I have Dell desktop with 32GB RAM and 1TB space and i7 CPU. I want to study OpenStack architecture, subsystems, operations on my desktop by DevStack.

Should I create separate VMs to build OpenStack sandbox OR use DevStack on single VM

~Ramnath